# How can you describe someone's height?

Tags: word-request

I know you can and, usually, do simply say 'tall' or 'short'. But what if I want to say it differently: 'of [some word] stature'. What adjectives should I use to make it sound idiomatic? 'Short'/'tall'? 'Low'/'high'?

Comment: That's a challenge, at least in the spoken sense, because 'stature' is not used much any more. It is slightly higher diction than tall/short. Of course you can get away with higher diction in writing and it does occur there. 'in' and 'of' are often used with a modifer before or after, as in 'small in stature.' Again, it's a bit more ponderous but it can be done - 'short in stature', 'diminutive in stature', 'of great stature', etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this might be somewhat subjective, I think the following all sound the most idiomatic when paired with *stature*:

> He is of **small** stature.
>   She is of **medium** stature.
>   They are of **large** stature.

---

With respect to its figurative use, the following is an example sentence from Merriam-Webster's definition of [*stature*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stature) (different emphasis mine):

> a man of surprisingly **great** stature.

On the other end of the scale (although it works both literally as well as figuratively) is:

> You are of **diminutive** stature.

---

To explicitly address a comment, I would not *short stature*.

For example:

> He is of short stature.
>
> → He is short.
>   → He is of small stature.

In fact, I would probably go with the simpler *he is short*. I don't see a real reason to use an *of statue* construction when discussing height, since the other is more succinct and common.

However, if I did use *stature*, I think that *small* works better with it in this context.

Comment: 'Short'? What d'you think?

Comment: I don't like *short* as much as I do *small* when it comes to pairing something with *stature*. If you were to use the word *short* (or *tall*) you could just leave out *stature* altogether—it doesn't add anything. I have updated my answer.

Comment: You see, the problem with 'small' is that it makes the phrase unnecessarily ambiguous: is it about someone's height or importance? I want it to be clear that it's about height

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev That's exactly why I wouldn't use *stature* at all. If you're talking about their height, simply say *He is short.* It doesn't get much clearer than that. (Even *short stature* could cause confusion.)

Comment: Why? You don't describe someone's importance as "short"

Comment: You first said you "don't like short as much as I do small" but now you say it "pairs better with short". It appears contradictory

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev I'm sorry, I mistyped in my last comment. I have deleted it to avoid further confusion. What I say at the end of my answer is accurate. To be explicit, if you are describing height, my personal preference would be to simply say *he is short* and not use *stature* at all. If you ***must*** use *stature*, it pairs better with *small*: *he is of small stature*. This is simply because of how things change idiomatically when the additional word is added. When combined with *stature*, *small* is better both figuratively (importance) and literally (height).

Answer (score 1):

This is something where Google's Ngram Viewer can help; searching for [`of * stature`](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=of+*+stature&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3) gives you the most common combinations:

[image]

Of course, you need to view the actual search results to view if they match your description. That seems to be the case for

- [of small stature](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22of%20small%20stature%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)

  > LITTLE GREAT MEN. IT is a remarkable thing that some of the greatest men in history have been of small stature. Certainly, from all experience, height of person has no influence on the mental faculties.
- [of great stature](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22of%20great%20stature%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)

  > Achilles was of great beauty, black Hairs and crispe, grey Eyes and great, of amiable sight, large Breasts, broad shoulders, great Arms, his Reins high enough, a man of great stature, and had none like unto him among all the Greeks
  >
  > There was yet a battle in Gath, says the Bible, where a man of great stature appeared, that had on each hand six fingers, and on each foot six toes, four and twenty in number; and he also was the son of the giant (Ibid.).

[short stature](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22of%20short%20stature%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en) seems to be used more in medical studies, which may not be what you're after.